# Autohokey: Change clipboard format from html to text

Tags: html, clipboard, autohotkey

How can I switch back to rich text after the several regex at the end of my script ( so I could past rich text and not HTML)?

This script copies a selected text, retrieve the HTML, format it (remove/change some html tags). So when I past the clipboard at the end, I have an html format. How can I rechange the format of the clipboard to get a text format when I past: I would like to be able to paste the clipboard  in MSWord for exemple instead of only in a html editor.

The actual code = text format → html format
The code I am looking for is : text format → html format→ text format
The code I am looking for could seem strange but I need to access the html tags to format them.

```
!^+k::                  ;Alt(!) CTRL(^) shift(+) AND c
clipboard =
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ESC}
ClipWait
;          Change clipboard content from text to html with tag
ClipboardGet_HTML( byref Data ) { ; http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=392624#392624
 If CBID := DllCall( "RegisterClipboardFormat", Str,"HTML Format", UInt )
  If DllCall( "IsClipboardFormatAvailable", UInt,CBID ) <> 0
   If DllCall( "OpenClipboard", UInt,0 ) <> 0
    If hData := DllCall( "GetClipboardData", UInt,CBID, UInt )
       DataL := DllCall( "GlobalSize", UInt,hData, UInt )
     , pData := DllCall( "GlobalLock", UInt,hData, UInt )
     , Data := StrGet( pData, dataL, "UTF-8" )
     , DllCall( "GlobalUnlock", UInt,hData )
 DllCall( "CloseClipboard" )
Return dataL ? dataL : 0
}

If ClipboardGet_HTML( Data ){
;     MsgBox, % Data
     clipboard = %Data%
; parse HTML to remove tag attributes - bcoz I want to apply a style on <span id="textmark...  I first replace them with a unique string that enable me to personalize their style after the parsing
HHSpanid := RegExReplace(clipboard, "<span id=""textmark", "TO2BE2REPLACED$0")
HHSpanidclass := RegExReplace(HHSpanid, "<span class=""textmark", "TO2BE2REPLACED$0")
Replacehtmlmarker := RegexReplace(HHSpanidclass, "<(p|span|div|img|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|h7|a|label|blockquote|form|svg|path|input|header|sup|br|iframe|button|time|nav)\K [^>]+(?=>)")
RemoveImg := RegExReplace(Replacehtmlmarker, "<img>", "")
ReplaceHHSpan := RegExReplace(RemoveImg, "TO2BE2REPLACED<span>", "<span style=""color: black;background-color: #ffff00;"">")
clipboard = %ReplaceHHSpan%
ClipWait
return
     }
Else SoundBeep
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WinClip](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74670-class-winclip-direct-clipboard-manipulations/) class.
Specifically `SetHTML( html, source = "" )` and `Paste( plainText = "" )`.